# Using third party libraries in code blocks (c++ project)

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to use third party allegro libraries in my cpp project. I have some questions about the process. So, I had to place three .dlls in my C:windows folder and then also link liballeg.a and include. Can someone explain to me conceptually what is going on here? I presume .dlls would be used to fetch cpp files code and include for headers. Then why is liballeg.a needs to be linked as well. 
Also, I had to place my files (include and lib directory) in the mingw directory of code blocks. Why was that needed?

Comment: No, dlls and a files have nothing to do with cpp files (although they were compiled from them).

Comment: Then whats the purpose of dlls and .a files here?

Comment: author of this lib writes code (functions, classes etc). Then he wants to distribute this. But this lib can be huge (or the author doesn't want everyone to know the source). So he builds a .dll or a .a file. You download this file and headers, include them into your project and then just link it with the lib. So you don't need to re-compile this (probably extremely big) library over and over again. That's one of the purposes.

Comment: That much I know. With allegro I placed the dlls in C:windows folder but also linked to linalleg.a (.a file) I was wondering why both were needed to be done.